# IDs are being duplicated between different instances of QGIS

Tags: qgis, duplication

Is there a way to create a secondary ID that cannot be duplicated?

Currently using 1 project between multiple instances of QGIS, this is resulting in this secondary field being duplicated which is causing issues later down the road, have tried setting the field as enforced unique and using auto to increment when each object is placed, have all instances save the layer after placing a new object, but still the IDs keep duplicating.
A shared database (postgres with a postgis plugin) is being used.
Just to iterate its not having an issue with the primary key, its a different field we are using as another form of identifier. UUID would not work as we are using it as a name of sorts for the object.

Edit:
Tried using `$id` however this does not work and always gives id of 0 as the id is not given until the object is saved and the other field does not auto update after this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what sort of datastore are you using? I would suggest a shared database would avoid this

Comment: You need to explain in the description, not in comments. Please add details as the request is not clear.

Comment: You could try to use the feature id of the current row ($id) concatenated with whatever you need as id, this should ensure uniqueness